# Having trouble pulling items from an sqlite table for use in Python

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

Just to start off, I'm very much just a beginner. Much of what I know, I've learned over the past two days from the internet. Now on to the problem.

I'm working on a project where the goal is to develop a text based trivia game in python. I'm using an sqlite3 database to store the information for the questions. The database layout consists of three columns with the first containing an ID number, the second containing a text string with the question and answer choices, and the third column containing the answer for it's respective question.

I can get the list to be created and pull blocks of information off of it easily, but the problem comes when I need to pull one row at a time. For maximum clarity, here's my code in full:

```
#imports necessary SQL connection files
import sqlite3
import sys

#Data to form the Question table
info = (
    ("Who invented the Golden Meme? A:Copericus  B:John Cena  C:Aristotle  D:Shie Lebeouf", "C"),
    ("What is the best chip flavor? A:Sour Cream & Onion  B:Salt & Vinegar  C:Barbecue  D:Moldy", "B"),
    ("Who will be prisident in 2017? A:Donald Trump  B:Bernie Sanders  C:Hillary Clinton  D:Ben Carson", "D"),
    ("Why? A:Becase he's smart and well educated  B:Because he's a doctor  C:Because once you go black you never go back  D:Because my IQ is less than 30", "C")
)


#Connects to the SQL database
con = sqlite3.connect('Questions.db')
cur = con.cursor()


#Deletes the Questions table if it already exists, then creates a new one containing all the data
with con:
    cur.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Questions''')
    cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE Questions(ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, question TEXT, answer TEXT)''')
    cur.executemany('''INSERT INTO Questions(question, answer) VALUES(?, ?)''', info)
    con.commit()

#Prints instructions
def instructions():
    print()
    print("INSTRUCTIONS: When a question is displayed, type the letter that corresponds to the desired answer choice. Type   using capital letters only. If you answer a question wrong, you will recieve a Failure message and the game will  end. If you answer all questions correctly, you win.")
    print()
    print()

#Displays which question the player is on
def counter():
    global n
    print("Question#", n)
    n = n+1
    nextQuestion()

#Displays the next question and recieves the players answer choice
def nextQuestion():
    cur.execute('''SELECT question FROM Questions''')
    Q = cur.fetchone()
    if Q == None:
        print()
        print("Victory!")
        print()
        return False;
    else:
        print (Q)
    playerAnswer = str(input("Your Answer: "))
    answerValidation(playerAnswer)

#Determines is the answer is correct and, if so, restarts the process
def answerValidation(playerAnswer):
    cur.execute('''SELECT answer FROM Questions''')
    B = cur.fetchone()
    if playerAnswer == B:
        print()
        print("Correct!")
        print()
        counter()
    else:
        print()
        print ("You Failed!")
        print(B)
        return False

n = 1
instructions()
counter()
```

The problem is that I can print the 1st question, but not any question after that. I was under the impression that `cur.fetchone()` was suppose to fetch the current line row and then move on to the next one, but when the code runs through for a second pass it just reprints the first question.

This is the section specifically pertaining to that problem.

```
def nextQuestion():
cur.execute('''SELECT question FROM Questions''')
Q = cur.fetchone()
if Q == None:
    print()
    print("Victory!")
    print()
    return False;
else:
    print (Q)
```

There is also a second problem. I'm also using the `cur.fetchone()` system to pull up the corresponding answer. It does fetch the correct answer, although probably just the first one as well, but the answer it fetches is still in the same format it was in the table. I put in a print B line to see what answer it was giving me and the result was `('C',)`. I think this is the reason whatever answer I put in always ends up false. Even if I put in C, the correct answer, it still counts it incorrect, most likely because the answer it pulled from the table has those apostrophes, parentheses, and comas in it.

If I change the code so that `playerAnswer in ['C','c']:` it will count the answer C correct and run back through the program pulling up the first question again.

Code pertaining to answer problem:

```
    playerAnswer = str(input("Your Answer: "))
    answerValidation(playerAnswer)

#Determines is the answer is correct and, if so, restarts the process
def answerValidation(playerAnswer):
    cur.execute('''SELECT answer FROM Questions''')
    B = cur.fetchone()
    if playerAnswer in ['C','c']:
        print()
        print("Correct!")
        print()
        counter()
    else:
        print()
        print ("You Failed!")
        print(B)
        return False
```

To sum it up, three main problems:

1. I can't get the program to print one question at a time and proceed to the next question only if the correct answer is given.
2. I can't get the program to accept the correct answer that corresponds to it's respective question.
3. I can't get the program to print the question and answer text outside of its stored format of `('X',)`

Any solutions, ideas, or help would be much appreciated.

It should also be noted that I designed the program to go through the questions in order (mostly because I thought it would be easier), but it does not have to work this way. If anyone can offer a solution that would fix the above problems, but chooses questions at random, I would very much appreciate that as well. It just has to be scalable and not display a question more than once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your questions:

**1./2.** `fetchone()` returns the next row of the current query.

For each question, you start a new query. Therefore your one `fetchone()`
   call returns always the first question.

You should also get the question and the corresponding answer in one query:
`SELECT question, answer FROM questions`. The way of two independent
queries works only if you query/use the question ID.

**3.** 
`fetchone()` returns the whole row as a tuple. To access the first field use an
index:

```
cur.execute('''SELECT answer FROM Questions''')
Q = cur.fetchone()
answer = Q[0]
```